# No Eevee Cursor on Snap Programs

Tags: mouse, snap, cursor

Hi I have a problem with snap packages It turns out that I have a pack of Eevee cursors converted from .ani to xcursor with RealWorld Cursor Editorbut the problem is that when using a snap program, it is not respected instead, DMZ-White appears and currently I no longer use default cursors instead I use custom animated cursors because of that I had to switch to flatpak because it respects my cursor[image: my main and standard cursor is an Eevee][image: what, there is no Eevee cursor on Firefox Snap]
is there any way for snap to recognize my cursor

Comment: The Snap developers did not intend to break custom cursors. Please file a bug report against snapd for this issue.

Comment: One of the reasons why I'm avoiding snap, they do not honor your desktop settings (besides startup is always slower) Try to find d deb package

Comment: When I updated from 21.04 to 21.10 I replaced the Firefox Apt with Snap and since it did not respect my Eevee cursor, I uninstalled Firefox Snap and changed it to Firefox Flatpak. For My Flatpak it is the future of Linux because it is more stable, starts faster and does not have many bugs like Snap

Comment: now we just have to wait for Canonical occurs to him to replace LibreOffice APT by Snap and obviously it will not respect my Eevee cursor, if this happens as usual I will uninstall the Snap version and install the Flatpak version

Comment: For those who love Eevee I have published this pack of cursors on Pling. Also in that same one there is a pack of Vulpix Cursors since together with Eevee they were my starters in Explorers of Sky and it is a very cute couple of little foxes. Do not use Snap if you are interested in this pack of cursors. The cursors were not created by me since I converted them to the xCursor format I gave the credit to the original creator called Noddles: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1660518